# falling star css animation with before/after

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make fallin star using css animation, so i created star with using pseudo element but i unable to set animation in pseudo element

```
 i{
     position: relative;
   width: 0; 
   height: 0; 
   border-left: 12px solid transparent; 
   border-right: 12px solid transparent; 
   border-bottom: 20px solid red;
}
 i:after {
  content:"";
   border-left: 12px solid transparent; 
   border-right: 12px solid transparent; 
   border-top: 20px solid red; 
   position: absolute;
   width: 0; 
   height: 0; 
   margin: 28px 0 0 -12px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m7bpp9za/

see the above fiddle which is falling "after pseudo element" but i need both i & i:after to get falling star

any suggestion would be great,
 Thanks

Comment: just a suggestion make i:after {margin: 23px 0 0 -12px;} for better star

Answer (score 2):

You were nearly there, you just need to change this line :

```
i, i:after
```

to

```
i
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m7bpp9za/1/)**

**Explanation :**

As the `i:after` pseudo element is positioned absolutely in the `i` element, it moves relatively to it so it "follows" it during the animation. Therefore it doesn't need to be animated.

Comment: Thanks for info but the fiddle is not falling

Comment: @parthiban as you set an animation delay you need to wait 2 seconds for the animation to start.

Comment: yes i wait more than that but still i couldn't find exactly what i miss. do you see anything falling on that demo. Or i mess up with position? Even i tried to change the position to absolute, but no help :(

Comment: @parthiban yes, the demo I linked is working for me, the stars are falling and rotating. try this one http://jsfiddle.net/m7bpp9za/9/

Comment: i tried with firefox in ubuntu is not working but for chrome is working any idea why it happen?

Comment: @parthiban this is because you didn't include the `-moz-` vendor prefixes in the CSS. Please accept answer if it help.